# extracting integral type from byte array

Tags: c++

I'm writing an integral type to a byte array like this:

```
unsigned char Data[10]; // Example byte array
signed long long Integer = 1283318; // arbitrary value
for (int i = 0; i < NumBytes; ++i)
    Data[i] = (Integer >> (i * 8)) & 0xff; // Set the byte
```

In this context, NumBytes is the number of bytes actually being written to the array, which can change - sometimes I'll be writing a short, sometimes a int, etc.

In a test case where I know NumBytes == 2, this works to retrieve the integral value:

```
signed short Integer = (Data[0] << 0) | (Data[1] << 8);
```

Based on this, I tried to do the same with a long long, so it would work for an arbitrary integral type:

```
signed long long Integer = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < NumBytes; ++i)
    Integer |= static_cast<signed long long>(Data[i]) << (i * 8);
```

But, this fails when Integer < 0. I'd be thankful if someone could point out what I'm missing here. Am I omitting the sign bit? How would I make sure this is included in a portable way?

Cheers!

Comment: Give a specific case where it fails (i.e. the value of `NumBytes`, the content of `Data[0...NumBytes-1]`, the value of `Integer` you actually got and the value you wanted.)

Comment: Why not use memcpy instead?

Comment: Seems to work fine with negative values: https://ideone.com/ABvMM8
Can you give specifics on compiler / system?

Comment: @mnistic It works in that example with NumBytes == 8. When you use an unsigned short as input and NumBytes becomes 2, that's when it no longer works. See https://ideone.com/9wCDWi

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    signed short Input = -288;
    int NumBytes = sizeof(signed long long);

    unsigned char Data[10]; // Example byte array
    signed long long Integer = Input; // arbitrary value
    std::cout << Integer << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumBytes; ++i)
        Data[i] = (Integer >> (i * 8)) & 0xff; // Set the byte
    signed long long Integer2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumBytes; ++i)
        Integer2 |= static_cast<signed long long>(Data[i]) << (i * 8);
    std::cout << Integer2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When you turn the short into the long long as you did in your code, the sign bit becomes the most significant bit in the long long, which means to correctly encode / decode it you need the all 8 bytes.

Comment: Right, so as soon as I truncate a larger integral type, the sign bit is the first thing I lose. The thing I was trying to do was minimize the number of used bytes for networking, so I'll have to rethink that. Thanks for helping me understand!